# How to set width of LinearLayout (with 7 TextView Elements), which is a child of HorizontalScrollView, so that only 4 are visible at a time?

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I have an LinearLayout (with 7 TextView Elements), within a HorizontalScrollView.
The HorizontalScrollView is set to fillViewport.
I want only 4 TextView elements to be visible at a time. The user can scroll to view the rest.

**Case 1:**
I am able get the required layout using layout_weight but then I am not able to scroll, as shown in the attached code. I am assuming the scroll doesn't work because weights are computed after GUI renders and so the width of the HorizontalScrollLayout doesn't change. Is that right?

**Case 2:**
If I fix the width, eg "60dp", Then it displays as required and I can scroll as well. However, this wont work on other screen sizes.

How can I achieve this effect in a way that it works with different screen sizes.

Here's the code for **Case 1**.

Layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="7">

        <TextView
            style="@style/ViewStyle"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ViewStyle"
            android:text="2" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ViewStyle"
            android:text="3" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ViewStyle"
            android:text="4" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ViewStyle"
            android:text="5" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ViewStyle"
            android:text="6" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ViewStyle"
            android:text="7" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="ViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: *I want only 4 TextView elements to be visible at a time.* - when the `LinearLayout` with the `TextViews` is first shown on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `layout_weight` in a `LinearLayout` wrapped in a `HorizontalScrollView` will not go well for what you want. I suggest you do something like this:

1. remove the `layout_weight` attribute from the `style`, also modify the `layout_width` to a value(or you could use `wrap_content`)
2. post a `Runnable` on one of your views in the `onCreate` method to update the text of the `TextViews` like this:

   ```
   // wrapperLinearLayout being your LinearLayout wrapping the 7 TextViews
   wrapperLinearLayout.post(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           // find out the width of the HorizontalScrollView
           HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) wrapperLinearLayout
                   .getParent();
           // the value below will be the new width of all the TextViews so
           // you can see only for initially
           int targetWidth = (hsv.getWidth() / 4) * 7;
           // modify the width of all 7 TextViews
           for (int i = 0; i < wrapperLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpc = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) wrapperLinearLayout
                       .getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams();
               lpc.width = targetWidth / 7;
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the screen width at runtime and then set width for your textviews. I suppose that's the only way you can get it to work.